# Insert results of SELECT Statement into SQL input Parameter

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a comma delimited list of column names that I am casting to XML and then selecting. I would like to then insert these into the `@selectedRows` input parameter, which will be called in a stored procedure. How do you insert these multiple values into the `@selectedRows` parameter? Thanks!

Convert Comma Delimited List to XML and Select:

```
DECLARE @xml as xml,@string as varchar(1000),@delimiter as varchar(10)
SET @string='Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5'
SET @delimiter =','
SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@string,@delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)
SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(25)') as value FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)
```

This will be in stored procedure:

```
Select @selectedRows
from Test
where TestField > TestField
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to split the comma delimited string of column names, but you would need to use dynamic sql for this something like this....

```
Declare @Sql NVarChar(Max);
Declare @string VarChar(1000) = 'Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5';

SET @Sql = N' SELECT ' + @string 
         + N' From Test '
         + N' where TestField > TestField'

Exec sp_executesql @Sql
```

Comment: Just a caution: that dynamic sql is the very definition of an injection attack waiting to happen.